# WSO2 - when user logins continuously user role gets removed and added after sometime automatically

Tags: authentication, ldap, wso2, role

I am using Wso2 IS(5.0.0) - LDAP(Read only userstore manager) as way to store and authenicate(oauth2) users. Also there is one role which is assigned to certain users. After each login, the user is checked if he has that role. Only if the user has that role, he is allowed to login.

The problem is when a user logins continuously his role gets removed automatically and gets added after sometime. This does not happen continuously or in certain interval. sometimes it happens every 15 mins and sometimes they happen once in an hour. Sometimes roles get added back after long interval say 20 mins. Why is this happening? Can this be resolved?

Comment: do u get any error logs?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne There is no error log but whenever this issue arises information log is  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - LDAP connection created successfully in read-only mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when you run your wso2 IS instance with h2 database. Switch to mysql or other stable database for your production or dev server. And Do not forget to apply the latest patch release for Identity server from wso2.

Thanks